# No Style Applying Without Verflow:Hidden Property To Any Section On Webpage

Tags: html, css, layout, frontend

I am creating a website based on Wordpress i am facing a very strange issue with each of the section, that when i apply any style specially the background color it does not apply directly, but when i add CSS property as follows:

```
.abc { 
    background-color:red;
    overflow:hidden:
 }
```

It starts work fine, and also when overflow property is not applied it not even highlighting the whole area of that section in Debug Mode.

Now the issue with the overflow property is i have some content cutting due to this as you can see in the following image:

[image]

And without overflow property the behavior of the section can be seen in the following image:

[image]

So now i want the background color to the section as well as to not cut the content as you can see in the first image. how i can fix this any quick solution will be appreciated.

consider the following structure

```
<header class="header-abc">
   ::before
   <div class="inner-abc-left">
         <img src="img.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="inner-abc-right">
         <ul class="navigation">
            <li> < href="#"> abc </a> </li>
            <li> < href="#"> abc </a> </li>
            <li> < href="#"> abc </a> </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</header>
```

Style is like:

```
.header-abc {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
 }
 .header-abc:before {
     display:inline;
 }
```

So with this style it is not working fine but added an additional overflow property make it work. keep in mind i am using wordpress with some pagebuilder and purchased theme.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code of how you are adding the style directly. It is not clear from the question.

Comment: @ApurvaSingh please check the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by my own this issue, it was due to a ::before tag to the header tag like below:

```
<header class="header-abc">
::before
</header>
```

so the ::before tag was given display:inline style that why it was blocking the style to be applied, now removed the inline property and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to solve this issue without having a link or a codepen so that we can at least see where this .abc div is located and what is it's relation to the rest of your code.